# Using post method with php,ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have struggle passing the value of an input from a form on a page to an other one, so here is the code : (PS: I'm french so sorry If my grammar is bad and I hope it's understandable)
This my page with the form :

Edit : I had made two mistake in this form, that have been corrected now. First I forgot the ' ' around mission_trans_select : `onclick="document.getElementById('mission_trans_select').value=(this.value)`
and second, an `echo` was missing in `value="<?php echo $line['MIS_ID_MISSION'];`

```
<html>
<form name="fListTran" id="fListTran" method="POST" action="index.php?page=missiontransfert">
    <div class="container">    
        <div id="loginbox"  class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">     
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" >
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title"><strong>Liste des missions de transfert</strong></div>
                        <div id="float"><a href="#"></a></div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="panel-body" >
                        <input name='name' id='mission_trans_select' type='hidden' value='' />
                            <strong>
                            <?php
                                echo "Il y a : ".$_Nbr_Missions_." missions trouvée(s).";
                                For($i=1;$i<=$_Nbr_Missions_;$i++){ //peut être mettre un max et donc tester le nombre de resultat
                            ?>
                            </strong>
                            <div class="btn-group-justified" id="mis-tran">
                            <a href="index.php?page=missiontransfert">
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" name="mission_tran" id="<?php echo $i ;?>" type="submit" value="<?php echo $line['MIS_ID_MISSION']; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('mission_trans_select').value=(this.value);">
                                <?php 
                                    echo $line['MIS_ID_MISSION'] .' - [' . $line['MIS_ID_DO'] . '] Emplacement actuel : ' 
                                            . $line['MIS_ID_AREA_SRC'] .'-'.$line['MIS_ID_BAY_SRC'].'-'.$line['MIS_ID_RACK_SRC'].'-'
                                            . $line['MIS_ID_STAGE_SRC'] .'<br> Priorité : '.$line['MIS_PRIORITE']
                                            .'- Produit : '.$line['PRO_LITERAL'] ; 
                                ?>
                                </button> 
                            </a>
                        </div>  
                        <?php
                            $line = oci_fetch_array($reqMisTranCount, OCI_ASSOC);
                            }
                        ?>
                        <a id="retour" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block" href="index.php?page=menu">
                            <span  class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></span> Retour</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

So to explain it I display a list of mission represented by buttons that the user can click on and each button is link to the page that I want to display an other form that require the value associated to the pressed button.

So as the id of the buttons depends of the numbers of row I obtain from my select query that I didn't show here but that works fine, I can't get the value from it so onClick of the button I set the value of the hidden input to the value of it.

The form as for action : `index.php?page=missiontransfert`, so in the index page I called my script loadJS.php where I try to use the post method with ajax but I don't get it.
Here is what I do so far :

```
<script>
if (document.getElementById("mission_trans_select").value!=''){
    var mis_id = document.getElementById("mission_trans_select").value;

}

function get_mis_id(element){                    
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","./ajax/ajaxlistetransfert.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "./transfert_list.php");
    xmlhttp.send(mis_id);
}
</script>
```

I don't know if it's correct or if it's the good way to do it... And also I don't know what to put into my ajax file (ajaxlistetransfert)

And finally is this the good way to obtain the post result in my file missiontransfert.php :

```
$_SESSION['MISMISSION']=$_POST['name'];
```

The 'name' was the name from the hidden input in my first form. 
Thanks for your help and time !

Comment: The if-clause in your js just burns my eyes. Set value/nothing to a variable first and then check if its nothing or something and do anything. but **NOT** get value in if-clause and then if its not nothing, get it again and do something with it.

Comment: @ksno I'm sorry, I have deleted this from my code, thanks for the lesson, I didn't know it was something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've included jQuery in your question tags, you can use simplified POST request syntax:

```
$.post('/ajax/ajaxlistetransfert.php',{
    mission_id: your_variable_holding_the_id
},function(result){
    alert(result); // alerts output of requested file.
})
```

and have your ajax PHP file make necessary operations with `$_POST['mission_id']` on the database/files and echoing the output
(ie. 'success'/'failure' string or a form element code that then could be appended to the requesting page)
 which then will be accesible to javascript as `result`